# How to mention schema name in dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: oracle

If I want to run this statement in SYS_LEE schema. 
How do I mention SYS_LEE schema name in below statement?

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','GET_EMPLOYEE_REC') from dual ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE', 'PROCEDURE_NAME', schema => 'SCHEMA_NAME') from dual
```

See documentation https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885